# Firefox Addon SDK - add eventListener for mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

i just started to create my first addon for firefox. At the moment i´m stuck in adding eventListeners via my addon.

I have a list of elements (ul li) where i want to add for each the mouseover and mouseout event. So far i just want to add an extra border to see that it is working.

But reading the documentation i cannot find an example how to do it. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks and KR

Comment: What have you tried already? What does your code look like? Please help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to know which is the best practice. I want to identify if the mouse will hover certain elements and than catch content of a sub-element. Should i use the attach tab method and inject jquery and there add the event listener?

Comment: Here's how to add a mouseover event to the addon's own elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322949/firefox-addon-sdk-onmouseover-event-for-a-button/34344292#34344292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found out how to do:

```
var qlist = document.querySelectorAll('ul#s-results-list-atf li.s-result-item');

for(var i = 0; i < qlist.length; i++) {

    qlist[i].addEventListener('mouseover',hoverEffectOn, false);

    qlist[i].addEventListener('mouseout',hoverEffectOff, false);

    qlist[i].addEventListener('click', showDataAsin, false);

}
```